# How to set a bitfield in a specific order and check later against the order

Tags: c

Let's say I have 3 functions within a system which can be called or not.
Later in my algorythm (see "*myMainFunction()*" below), I'm interested to know if all the functions are called or not.

Actually to track if my functions are called I use a helper function which sets a 16 bitfield:

```
static void SetBitField(u16 p_Bitfield, u8 Bit)
{
   u16 tmp_Bitmask;

   tmp_Bitmask = (u16)((u16)(1) << (u16)(Bit));

   *p_Bitfield |= tmp_Bitmask;

}
```

Now in my functions I'm doing the following:

```
static u16 BitMask;

#define SHIFT_0     0
#define SHIFT_1     1
#define SHIFT_2     2

#define MASK        7

fun1()
{
/*doing some stuff*/

SetBitField(&BitMask,SHIFT_0)

}

fun2()
{

/*doing some stuff*/

SetBitField(&BitMask,SHIFT_1)
}

fun3()
{

/*doing some stuff*/

SetBitField(&BitMask,SHIFT_2)
}
```

And now in the main function I can check if all the functions are called

```
    myMainFunction()
    {

    /*doing some stuff*/

    if ((BitMask & MASK) == MASK)
    {
        /*all functions are called*/
    }

    /*doing some stuff*/
}
```

This is fine so far. But on the end I will get the same BitMask no matter in which order the functions are called.
But how to modify the SetBitField() function in the way that I can later check if my functions are called in a specific order.
For example to check that func1() --> func2() --> func3() is called and not for example func2() --> func1() --> func3()?

Any idea?

Comment: You need to store that information somewhere. Create separate multiple bitfields and store the bitfield history, have an array of bitfields to store which function run first, allocate a string to store function names in it.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. ***Why*** do you need the functions to be called in a specific order? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve by this? And if you're doing the programming, why can't you just make sure that the functions are called in the order you want?

Comment: Use some logging maybe? If you have just 3 functions you can set the most significant bit and then shift right SHIFT_X times, then you can decode it,

Comment: In addition to the above comments, this seems like something that could be very easily done with `gdb`, plus in general its a great tool to learn how to use. I would recommend that.

Comment: @perreal Would it be possible that you show this on the example above?

Comment: @perreal *Use some logging maybe?* Indeed.  The simplest way to find out what a program does **is to have it tell you**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You cannot know which way the train went by looking at the tracks" and neither can you know in which order the functions were called by looking at the bits. They will only tell you that the function was called, but not in which order.

The following does however:

```
struct BITMASK {
    unsigned int b1:3;
    unsigned int b2:3;
    unsigned int b3:3;
    unsigned int b4:3;
    unsigned int b5:3;
    unsigned int b6:3;
    unsigned int b7:3;
} myBits;
int counter;

static void SetBitField(u8 Bit)
{
    switch (Bit) {
    case 0: myBits.b1= ++counter; return;
    case 1: myBits.b2= ++counter; return;
    case 2: myBits.b3= ++counter; return;
    case 3: myBits.b4= ++counter; return;
    case 4: myBits.b5= ++counter; return;
    case 5: myBits.b6= ++counter; return;
    case 6: myBits.b7= ++counter; return;
    }
}
```

So here you are using three bits (max seven function calls) to hold a number which is the order of invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Given 3 functions and shift values (1, 2, 3).

If you apply this rule upon function invocation:

- set the most significant bit, then shift right by the respective value.

For the given (order), you will get [these bits]:

```
(1, 2, 3) [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
(1, 3, 2) [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
(2, 1, 3) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
(2, 3, 1) [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
(3, 1, 2) [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
(3, 2, 1) [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

The python script that generated the bits for example purposes:

```
import itertools                             

def mark(v, x):                              
  v[0] = 1                                   
  v = [0] * x + v[:-x]                       
  return v                                   

for x in itertools.permutations([1,2,3]):    
  v = [0] * 8                                
  for xx in x:                               
    v = mark(v, xx)                          
  print x, v
```

Comment: Thank you for the tipps! At the end it's easier than I expexted.